# Are you allowed to use another company's logo for a graphic design project?

Tags: logo, copyright

I want to create a booklet about NIKE for a school project & I also want to keep it in my design portfolio. Am I allowed to use the Nike Logo?

Comment: Are you affiliated with Nike by any chance? ;-)

Comment: From their website: `"It's your responsibility to determine whether your proposed use is legally permissible. For example, some uses of Nike logos in a textbook may be considered “fair use."`. Since it's a school project and doesn't have any commercial purposes I guess it's ok.

Comment: User552853, post that comment as an answer please. If you can link to the website page you got that would be nice.

Answer (score 4):

To formulate an answer:

This is quoted from their website:

> "It's your responsibility to determine whether your proposed use is legally permissible. For example, some uses of Nike logos in a textbook may be considered “fair use."

Usually there is nothing wrong with using logos or brand names for school projects or even 'practice' projects for your portfolio as long as you make it *really* clear it is just a concept for practice and the respected company has nothing to do with it.

If you want to see how other people formulate this, search on popular design sites such as dribbble for *'redesign concept'* and you'll find many concepts.

Answer (score 1):

I think their won't be any problem with that, as it's your school project and you are not going to use to it for your personal benefit.

As your complete project is based on particular brand so some where in the project you will require to use that logo.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure it will be fairly obvious that what you used it for was a school project. However, just make sure it's clear when presenting your portfolio for job interviews. You don't want to misrepresent that you did work for the actual company. This won't hurt your portfolio, if the work is good it won't matter if it was a school project, spec job, or actual client.